# Add method imports to shell_plus with alias

Tags: django, django-extensions

I have a model naming collision in my django models, with 2 models called `Tag` in separate modules.  That looks something like this:

```bash
.
├── conversations/
│   └──models.py           <- contains a model called Tag
└── dogs/
    └──models.py           <- contains a model called Tag
```

In shell_plus I want to import each module with an alias in `SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS` so that it's available when I start the shell.  How can I do this?

As an example, if i were doing this manually in shell_plus I'd write:

```py
# These are the imports I want to happen automatically:
from conversation import models as conversation_models
from dogs import models as dog_models

# Then I can write:
conversation_models.Tag()
dog_models.Tag()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings you can specify additional imports:

```
SHELL_PLUS_IMPORTS = [
    'from conversations.models import Tag as ConversationsTag',
    'from dogs.models import Tag as DogsTag',
]
```